# Is this plant with very asymmetric leafes Aegopodium podagraria (aka ground elder)?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I found this plant in a city park in Germany. The leaves were about 20cm of height; the smell of the squeezed leaves was a bit like carrots. The stems were edged. So I guess it was [Aegopodium podagraria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegopodium_podagraria) (aka *ground elder*), but I'm not sure about it.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A man, collecting herbs, confirmed my suggestion about Aegopodium podagraria. Together with what I read about this plant, I can set my question as being answered with **Yes**.